# React Native iOS app is showing cached data

Tags: php, ios, iphone, react-native

I am working on my first React Native project. While testing the iOS version of the application using Simulator I came to know that the app is showing cached data.

My use case is like, In the first page I am showing a list of images and upon clicking on the image user will be navigated to description page. These  descriptions are fetched from the server each time user visit this page. But when I change the descriptions in the server database its not reflecting the app.

Please guide me to fix this issue. I have also observed that the behaviour is same in real device.

Answer (score 0):

Found some limitations to GET requests as follows:

- GET requests can be cached
- GET requests remain in the browser history
- GET requests can be bookmarked
- GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
- GET requests have length restrictions
- GET requests should be used only to retrieve data

Some + points on POST requests:

- POST requests are never cached
- POST requests do not remain in the browser history
- POST requests cannot be bookmarked
- POST requests have no restrictions on data length

Reference https://codeburst.io/integrating-react-native-apps-with-back-end-code-using-fetch-api-8aeb83dfb428